# Replace certain text

Tags: php, preg-replace, strpos

I have the following code:

```
    <?php
$actual_link = "domain.com/search/q/laptop/attr/price_range_11_50005/attr/23914175_laptop";
        if ($attribute->name == "Price range")
        {
            if (strpos($actual_link,'/attr/price_range_') !== false)
                {
                    $querystring = explode("&",preg_replace(array("/attr/price_range_[0-9_]+/", "", $actual_link)));
                }
            else
                {
                    $querystring = explode("&",$actual_link);
                }
                }
        }
```

For some reason its not working, the code should replace the current "/attr/price_range" with nothing on the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong:

```
preg_replace(array("/attr/price_range_[0-9_]+/", "", $actual_link)
```

As you are using the forward slash `/` as the [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), you need to escape it or use a different delimiter:

```
preg_replace(array("/\/attr\/price_range_[0-9_]+/", "", $actual_link)
```

or

```
preg_replace(array("#/attr/price_range_[0-9_]+#", "", $actual_link)
```

Comment: Hi, does it matter if there is a "_" between the numbers? for example price_range_11_50005

Comment: @user3134976 No, `[0-9_]+` is a sequence of 1 or more of the characters in the character class in any order.